# [Nodes]Straight displacement for UV Sphere

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to get a straight displacement through nodes only. My goal is to create a lollipop.
I'm trying to create the lollipop stick. How can I obtain a straight displacement and not a cone shape (see picture below) ?

Thank you for your help !
PS : sorry, english is not my main language

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What does your starting mesh look like? Is it a sphere?

Comment: Yes, It is a simple UV Sphere with subdivision surface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using cycles with experimental feature set. 
On the uv sphere i am adding adaptive subdivision.

- Selecting the area to extrude with less than node

  [image: Selecting the area to extrude with less than node]
- Adding vector displacement

  [image: Adding vector displacement]
- The multiply node is used to change the displacement distance
- combine xyz node is used to get the -z direction. The displacement will occurs in this direction.
- The normal displacement node displaces along the surface normals, hence you get a conical displacement

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I'll try this